# Video Stream to server

Tags: android, android-intent, stream, video-streaming, android-2.2-froyo

I have a class which records in the background, and takes GPS location.

Now the problem is that I need to stream the video in real-time to server secured (Later.), But a local computer would do awesome for now.

How should I make this happened?

Background Recorder class:

```
public class RecorderService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "RecorderService";
    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private static Camera mServiceCamera;
    private boolean mRecordingStatus;
    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;

    // GPSTracker class
    GPSTracker gps;
    Geocoder geocoder;
    String addressString;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mRecordingStatus = false;
        //mServiceCamera = CameraRecorder.mCamera;
        mServiceCamera = Camera.open();
        mSurfaceView = MainActivity.mSurfaceView;
        mSurfaceHolder = MainActivity.mSurfaceHolder;

        super.onCreate();
        if (mRecordingStatus == false)
            startRecording();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        stopRecording();
        mRecordingStatus = false;

        super.onDestroy();
    }   

     //Start recording class.
    public boolean startRecording(){

        // create class object
        gps = new GPSTracker(RecorderService.this);

        // check if GPS enabled     
        if(gps.canGetLocation()){

            double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            double longitude = gps.getLongitude();


            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"latitude: " + latitude + "  longitude: "+ longitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),GetAddress(latitude,longitude), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  

        }else{

            // can't get location
            // GPS or Network is not enabled
            // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
            gps.showSettingsAlert(); }

        gps.stopUsingGPS();



        //Try to start the backgroun recording
        try {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Recording Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //mServiceCamera = Camera.open();
            Camera.Parameters params = mServiceCamera.getParameters();
            mServiceCamera.setParameters(params);
            Camera.Parameters p = mServiceCamera.getParameters();

            final List<Size> listSize = p.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            Size mPreviewSize = listSize.get(2);
            Log.v(TAG, "use: width = " + mPreviewSize.width 
                        + " height = " + mPreviewSize.height);
            p.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
            p.setPreviewFormat(PixelFormat.YCbCr_420_SP);
            mServiceCamera.setParameters(p);

            try {
                mServiceCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
                mServiceCamera.startPreview();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mServiceCamera.unlock();

            mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mServiceCamera);
            mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
            mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/video.mp4");
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
            mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder.getSurface());

            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
            mMediaRecorder.start(); 

            mRecordingStatus = true;

            return true;
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    //Stops Recording
    public void stopRecording() {

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Recording Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {
            mServiceCamera.reconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mMediaRecorder.stop();
        mMediaRecorder.reset();

        mServiceCamera.stopPreview();
        mMediaRecorder.release();

        mServiceCamera.release();
        mServiceCamera = null;
    }

    //Gets the adress, if not it will just return nothing. 
    public String GetAddress(Double lat, Double lon)
    {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);
        String ret = "";
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 1);
            if(addresses != null) {
                Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("Address:\n");
                for(int i=0; i<returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                }

                try{
                    //Createas a file with the GPS location.
                    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("/sdcard/adress.txt", getBaseContext().MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                    fos.write(strReturnedAddress.toString().getBytes());
                    fos.close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e){

                    }

                ret = strReturnedAddress.toString();
            }
            else{
                ret = "No Address returned!";
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            ret = "Can't get Address!";
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```